# Exchange Relay Error 550 5.7.367

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, relay

I've got a somewhat unique situation. I work for an MSP and am running into the aforementioned email relay issue.

Basically, an email from a client is being sent to a distribution list on our domain. That distribution list's members are on a different external domain. Essentially:

Client->MSP->3rd Party

Of course, it kicks back because we're trying to auto forward to an external domain and the originating domain does not have permission to send to 3rd Part in that manner.

The fix that I've read is to set up connectors that basically whitelist this behavior based on IP, but in this case we'd have to set up 50 or so of these connectors to cover all clients. The simple fix is to just have the Client email the 3rd Party directly, cutting out the middle man, but I'm pressed to find a solution because they want our domain to be tied/associated with the email the client is sending.

Is there a cover-all solution that doesn't compromise security, or am I still looking at creating a connector for every single client that needs to email this list?

Comment: You need to give relay permission to the users on this server.

Comment: @harrymc How is that accomplished? MSP and 3rd party use O365. Is this giving relay permission on MSP or 3rd party server? [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365#option-3-configure-a-connector-to-send-mail-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365-smtp-relay) seems to be the potential fix, but it seems a bit ridiculous to have to setup one of these for each domain I want to give permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to find a way to allow the client to send an email to the distribution list on your domain while being associated with your domain without having to set up a connector for every single client. From what you have described, there is no way to do this without compromising security. The best solution may be to have the client email the 3rd Party directly, as you suggested.

Comment: I figured this was the case. Thanks for the clarification!